# Зачем нужен тег meta в html?

Tags: html, language-lawyer

Например для того, чтобы на сайте обозначить автора в теге head, нужно прописать данную строчку кода:

```
<meta name="author" content="(имя автора)">
```

Но зачем, если можно было сделать например так:

```
<author>(имя автора)</author>
```

Пробовал найти в интернете нужную информацию, но не нашёл.

Comment: Очевидно оттого, что те, кто придумывал спецификацию языка HTML, решили, что информация об авторе страницы относится к метаданным страницы. Хотя в спецификации HTML 5 и появилась возможность использовать `rel="author"` в некоторых тегах.

Comment: @Quazimorda но неочевидно почему они так решили

Comment: @andreymal вот только не нужно никого тролить :))) Отдельные теги author charset  и прочча не существуют, а в виде метаданных они объединены, как будто это всё одна сущность. Метаданные, которые не отображаются на веб-странице, но важны для поиска и прочих seo.

Comment: @Quazimorda почему не существуют? Почему объединены? Что мешало сделать невидимый тег `<author>` для поиска и прочих seo? Ничего не понятно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Но зачем, если можно было сделать например так:
>
> ```
> <author>(имя автора)</author>
> ```

Короткий ответ: для облегчения расширяемости и совместимости.

[Спецификация HTML 2.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1866) (в которой, кажется, появилась эта возможность) не предусматривала какого-то фиксированного списка метаданных, которыми можно описать документ. Это было оставлено на усмотрение авторов конкретного html-документа.
HTML как язык разметки документов происходил из академической среды, разные пользователи могли в своих хранилищах документов и инструментах обработки опираться на разные метаданные.
Поэтому и был предложен механизм указывать произвольные key-value пары через тег `<META name="" content="">`.

Если бы разработчики пошли по пути "отдельные 'невидимые' теги для каждой разновидности метаданных", то пришлось бы всякий раз при появлении нового такого тега выпускать новую версию спецификации. Это в свою очередь могло бы сломать совместимость в уже существующих браузерах или ином ПО.

Аналогичная ситуация, в варианте использования для указания веб-серверу необходимости включить в ответ заголовки через `<META http-equiv="" content="">`. Разные веб-сервера могут использовать какие-то специфичные заголовки (HTTP это позволяет). То есть полный список наименований заранее не известен.

Answer (score 1):

Тег `<meta>` определяет метаданные о HTML-документе. Метаданные представляют собой данные (информацию) о данных.

Теги `<meta>` всегда располагаются внутри элемента `<head>` и обычно используются для указания набора символов (`character set`), описания страницы, ключевых слов, автора документа и настроек области просмотра (`viewport`).

Метаданные не отображаются на странице, но предназначены для обработки компьютером.

Браузеры используют метаданные для определения, как отображать содержимое или перезагружать страницу, а поисковые системы используют ключевые слова. Кроме того, метаданные используются другими веб-сервисами.

Помимо того, что можно установить автора (`name="author"`), мы можем

- устанавливать кодировку:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

- Описание страницы для поисковых систем:

```
<meta name="description" content="Это описание">
```

- Установку ключевых слов для поисковых систем

```
<meta name="keywords" content="слово1, слово2, слово3">
```

- Отключать кэширование

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

- Автоматически перенаправлять на другие страницы

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=https://www.example.com/новая-страница">
```

---

P.S. чот не видел я чтоб существовал тэг `author`, но как сказал в комментариях @Quazimorda, есть HTML5 и в его стандартах прописано использование `rel="author"`

---

UPD1

Провел ресерч, тэга `<author>` не существует, если ошибаюсь, приложите источник в комментарии

Comment: На вопрос-то не ответили. Почему не `<author>` и не `<charset>` и не `<keywords>` и так далее по аналогии?

Comment: Момент @andreymal, дописываю ответ на лету

Comment: @andreymal, все просто, таких тэгов не существует

Comment: Ну так почему таких тэгов не существует?)

Comment: @andreymal не могу знать, возможно автор вопроса их выдумал, а отвечать на ваш вопрос это то же самое что и отвечать на "почему ты не сделал яичницу сегодня?", ну нет и нет таких тэгов, не существует

Comment: @andreymal а главный вопрос звучит как **"Зачем нужен тег meta в html?"**

Comment: Очевидно, что автор их выдумал, ну так в том и суть вопроса, почему их выдумал он, а не разработчики стандарта HTML )

Answer (score 0):

Ну хорошо, вот вам краткий ответ. Тег **Meta** в HTML нужен для того, чтобы в нём объединить все метаданные, которые не выводятся на веб-странице, но влияют на её вывод и помогают поисковым роботам и прочим seo.

Но ответ Acinit - развёрнутый и потому лучше моего.

Comment: я плюсанула, только вот, я слышала, что по-моему программисты часто злоупотребляли этими тегами, и теперь эта информация не совсем верная , ---->что помогают поисковым роботам и прочим seo(,,,чтоб ставить вперед листа тот или иной сайт для более удобного поиска)‍♀️

Comment: @Dev18 Не исключено, что вы правы. Как по мне, то неправильные адреса, ведущие не на те сайты, неверные описания страниц так же плохи как и вообще отсутствие оных. Но это совсем другая история. Ответ Nofate считаю наиболее точным. ))